# Updating state based on different button clicks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, axios, state

I am trying to make a survey tool with firebase and react and I am implementing a template feature, so now one of the templates is working, when user clicks on create new survey, I have various buttons shown to them like: blank, temp1,temp2,temp3,temp4 based on whatever is clicked a clickhandler is triggered, now how do I update the content of the state based on which template i am getting? below is my code:

```
<button onClick={props.clicked} className={classes.Board}>
        Board Survey
      </button>
      <button onClick={props.chair} className={classes.Chair}>
        Chairperson Survey
      </button>
      <button onClick={props.member} className={classes.Member}>
        Board Member Survey
      </button>
```

And now i use

```
clicked={this.clickHandler}
```

The code to fetch survey template:

```
const fetchSurvey = async () => {
  const res = await axios.get(
    "/surveys/ckb0kmt3n000e3g5rmjnfw4go/content/questions.json"
  );
  return res.data;
};
```

Where "ckb0kmt3n000e3g5rmjnfw4go" is the survey id

```
 const content = {
  title: "Your Survey Tite",
  subTitle: "Your Survey Description",
  creatorDate: new Date(),
  lastModified: new Date(),
  questions: fetchSurvey().then(questions => {
    this.setState(state => ({
      ...state,
      content: {
        ...state.content,
        questions
      }
    }));
  }),
  submitting: true
};

this.setState({
  _id: newId(),
  content: content,
  userId: this.props.user_Id
});
}
```

Now how to do i update the questions key to run different functions based on which templates i choose on the previous page?

ClickHandler Code:

```
clickHandler = () => {
const newSurvey = { ...this.state };
axios
  .put(
    "/surveys/" + this.state._id + ".json?auth=" + this.props.token,
    newSurvey
  )
  .then(res => {
    this.props.onGetSurveyId(res.data._id);
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

};

File1:

```
    import React from "react";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";
import Icon from "@material-ui/core/Icon";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import classes from "./NewSurvey.module.css";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import Dialog from "@material-ui/core/Dialog";
import DialogActions from "@material-ui/core/DialogActions";
import DialogContent from "@material-ui/core/DialogContent";
import DialogTitle from "@material-ui/core/DialogTitle";
import InputLabel from "@material-ui/core/InputLabel";
import Input from "@material-ui/core/Input";
import MenuItem from "@material-ui/core/MenuItem";
import FormControl from "@material-ui/core/FormControl";
import Select from "@material-ui/core/Select";
import { ToastContainer, toast } from "react-toastify";
import "react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css";

const NewSurvey = props => {
  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);
  const [template, setTemplate] = React.useState("");

  const handleChange = event => {
    setTemplate(Number(event.target.value) || "");
  };

  const handleClickOpen = () => {
    setOpen(true);
  };

  const handleClose = () => {
    setOpen(false);
  };

  const notify = () =>
    toast.info("Creating Survey....Please Wait", {
      position: "top-right",
      autoClose: 5000,
      hideProgressBar: true,
      closeOnClick: true,
      pauseOnHover: true,
      draggable: true,
      progress: undefined
    });

  return (
    <div className={classes.CreateSurvey}>
      <ToastContainer
        position="top-right"
        autoClose={5000}
        hideProgressBar
        newestOnTop
        closeOnClick
        rtl={false}
        pauseOnFocusLoss
        draggable
        pauseOnHover
      />
      <Dialog
        disableBackdropClick
        disableEscapeKeyDown
        open={open}
        onClose={handleClose}
        className={classes.Dialog}
      >
        <DialogTitle className={classes.DialogTitle}>
          Create New Survey
        </DialogTitle>
        <h5 className={classes.Info}>
          Choose a template or start with a blank survey
        </h5>
        <DialogContent>
          <button
            onClick={function(event) {
              props.clicked();
              notify();
            }}
            className={classes.Blank}
          >
            Blank Survey
          </button>
          <button onClick={props.board} className={classes.Board}>
            Board Survey
          </button>
          <button onClick={props.chair} className={classes.Chair}>
            Chairperson Survey
          </button>
          <button onClick={props.member} className={classes.Member}>
            Board Member Survey
          </button>
        </DialogContent>
        <DialogActions>
          <button onClick={handleClose} className={classes.CancelButton}>
            Cancel
          </button>
        </DialogActions>
      </Dialog>
      <button
        className={classes.NewSurvey}
        onClick={handleClickOpen}
        disabled={props.isLoading || props.error}
      >
        <Icon className={classes.Icon}>add_circle_outline</Icon> Create New
        Survey
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default NewSurvey;
```

File 2:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { withRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import newId from "../../../ulitity/idGenerator";
import axios from "../../../axios-order";

import * as actionTypes from "../../../Store/actions/actionsTypes";
import NewSurveyView from "../../../Components/NewSurvey/NewSurvey";
import { InitQuestions } from "../../../ulitity/constants/Questions";

class NewSurvey extends Component {
  state = {
    _id: "",
    userId: "",
    content: {
      title: "Your Survey Title",
      subTitle: "",
      creatorDate: "",
      lastModified: ""
    }
  };
  componentDidMount() {
    var sampleQuestion;
    var questionObj;
    sampleQuestion = InitQuestions["SINGLE_LINE_TEXT"]();
    questionObj = {
      [sampleQuestion._id]: sampleQuestion
    };
    var orderQuestions;
    let questions = [sampleQuestion._id];
    orderQuestions = questions.map(questionId => questionObj[questionId]);
    const fetchBoardMember = async () => {
      const res = await axios.get(
        "/surveys/ckb0kmt3n000e3g5rmjnfw4go/content/questions.json"
      );
      return res.data;
    };

    const fetchBoard = async () => {
      const res = await axios.get(
        "/surveys/ckb24goc800013g5r7j8igrk3/content/questions.json"
      );
      return res.data;
    };

    const fetchChair = async () => {
      const res = await axios.get(
        "/surveys/ckb24gt3s00053g5rrf60353r/content/questions.json"
      );
      return res.data;
    };

    const content = {
      title: "Your Survey Title",
      subTitle: "Your Survey Description",
      creatorDate: new Date(),
      lastModified: new Date(),
      questions: fetchBoard().then(questions => {
        this.setState(state => ({
          ...state,
          content: {
            ...state.content,
            questions
          }
        }));
      }),
      submitting: true
    };

    this.setState({
      _id: newId(),
      content: content,
      userId: this.props.user_Id
    });
  }

  clickHandler = () => {
    const newSurvey = { ...this.state };
    axios
      .put(
        "/surveys/" + this.state._id + ".json?auth=" + this.props.token,
        newSurvey
      )
      .then(res => {
        this.props.onGetSurveyId(res.data._id);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <NewSurveyView
          clicked={this.clickHandler}
          board={this.boardHandler}
          chair={this.chairHandler}
          member={this.memberHandler}
          isLoading={this.props.loading}
          error={this.props.isError}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    user_Id: state.auth.userId,
    token: state.auth.token,
    surveyId: state.surveyEditer.survey.id
  };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    onGetSurveyId: surveyId =>
      dispatch({ type: actionTypes.GET_SURVEY_ID, surveyId: surveyId })
  };
};

export default withRouter(
  connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(NewSurvey)
);
```

Comment: I take it you are using react? You will need to provide your entire example. props.clicked does not appear to exist in your example so will mean nothing.

Comment: Im sorry, i forgot to add the click handler code, and yes I am using react, the question has been updated :)

Comment: @SteveTomlin sorry as I'm a newbie

Comment: What I mean is you need to provide the whole component which includes this code: <button onClick ....

Comment: @SteveTomlin That code is not important, basically when im clicking the button, OnCLickHandler is getting activated, nothing more

Comment: it is important to me to help. I dont know what props.clicked means. I need to see all the props being passed into the component.

Comment: @SteveTomlin I have added the entire code for both the files, kindly help me out :)